# Remove jquery event handlers using .off() or .empty()

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

I have some little widgets in an application that when created/initialized attach a series of event handlers to the main container element.

```
widget = function(){
    this.el = $("#someelement");
    this.init = function(){
        doAjax(function(data)){
            this.el.html(data)
            .on("click", function(){
                //attach some handler here
            })
            .on("change", ("div.class"), function(){
                //attach some handler here
            });
        } 
    }
    this.reload = function(){
        this.init();
    }
}
```

My problem is obvious here - whenever I reload the widget (calling the init function) I re-attach even handlers to the element. Then if I trigger a handler it is done for as many times as I have "refreshed". I have tried multiple things:

```
this.el.empty().html(data)
this.el.off("*").html(data)
this.el.html(data)
.off("click change")
this.el.children.remove().end().html(data)
```

So on and so forth. Nothing I do actually removes the event handlers. All I can do is append/add them. I can never clear them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you use `on()`, there should be no need to re-attach every time.

Comment: @Xander - init is called simply because I get data via ajax and load it into the element the widget is attached to. It is called to refresh that data. I've considered breaking it out somehow, but haven't fully thought through that yet.

Comment: yea breaking it out and use a single on is much better

Comment: You'd be better off writing the plugin in such a way that prevents it from being initialized again. If the plugin is called on an element that has already been initialized, don't bind the events again, just do any "reinitialization" that needs to happen.

Comment: @Huangism - what exactly do you mean by using a single ON? I gave a very barebones example. I have multiple of these widgets that have many event handlers attached to many different elements. how would I go about only having a single .on()?

Comment: so i assume multiple of the same widget - can't you just add a class to whatever element that needs the handler to be attached and target that class with .on()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
widget = function(){
    this.el = $("#someelement");
    this.isInitialLoad = false;

    this.init = function(){
        doAjax(function(data)){
            if(!isInitialLoad){
                this.el.html(data)
                .on("click", function(){
                    //attach some handler here
                })
                .on("change", ("div.class"), function(){
                    //attach some handler here
                });
            }
            else {
                this.el.html(data);
            }
        } 
    }
    this.reload = function(){
        this.init();
    }
}
```

Or, separating concerns:

```
widget = function(){
    this.el = $("#someelement");

    this.init = function(){
        doAjax(function(data) {
            this.el.html(data)
            .on("click", function(){
                //attach some handler here
            })
            .on("change", ("div.class"), function(){
                //attach some handler here
            });
        });
    }
    this.reload = function(){
        doAjax(function(data) { this.el.html(data); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Without trying this out, it seems very close to looking like it would work well. The only problem is that the "this.el.html(data)" line is inside the if not initialized check, which would make the reload function simply do an ajax call, but then do nothing with the result.

Comment: look at the else statement. also the second version is better.

Comment: ah - missed the else the first time.